# What does the electrolytic capacitor specification E 9 A 105 CF mean?

Tags: capacitor, specifications

What do these electrolytic capacitor specifications mean?

- E 9 A
- 105 \$^\circ\$CF

Is its maximum temperature 105 Celcius or 105 Farenheit? It has both letters.

Comment: E9A is likely a manufacturer specific designation. It's Celcius.

Comment: 105F wouldn't be very useful at all. It's Celsius.

Comment: The data sheet will give you that information.